# Can I change a distribution parameters?

Tags: c++, random

There is uniform_int_distribution in [< random >](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)
When I creating that I define an interval.
Can I change this interval after the creation?

for example

```
std::uniform_int_distribution distr(0, 10);
// can I change an interval here ?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just assign a new distribution to the variable:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 10);

distr = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(5, 13);
```

Or, create a parameter for that (@awesomeyi answer required distribution object creation, this still requires param_type object creation)

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 10); 

distr.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(5, 13));
```

Proof that param_type will work (for @stefan):

> P is the associated param_type. It shall satisfy the
>   CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and EqualityComparable
>   requirements. It also has constructors that take the same arguments of
>   the same types as the constructors of D and has member functions
>   identical to the parameter-returning getters of D

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution

Comment: Is the `param_type` guaranteed to have an constructor taking two values? I can't find anything on cppreference.com

Comment: @stefan, for uniform_int_distribution? yes, you can see it by following the `param_type` declaration.

Comment: I don't see any requirement on the param_type constructors in the standard. Can you point me towards it? All I can see there is, that `param_type` is a `typedef unspecified param_type`. This would suggest, that there is no guarantee for such a constructor.

Comment: @stefan, added the link

Comment: I found the corresponding clause: it's 26.5.1.6 [rand.req.dist] 9.

Answer (score 3):

You can through the `param()` function.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 10);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type d2(2, 10);
distr.param(d2);
```

Comment: i.e I need a new object anyway... It is sad :(

Comment: @vlad4378 It's probably not that bad. You're not constantly switching ranges, right? And if the size of the range is the same for all, you can just add an offset.

Comment: @vlad4378 For example if you first use an distribution for values between 0 and 10, but later between 10 and 20, you can use the same distribution object, but simply add 10 to all values.

Comment: @ Thank you, it's way

Comment: @stefan So, if i had ditr. between 0 to 10, and later 0 ... 7 , it doesn't help