# How to use std::uniform_int_distribution<T>::param()?

Tags: c++, random, uniform-distribution

I would like to be able to reset the lower and upper bounds of a `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>` object after it has been created, and it seems the `param` function in the class allows this functionality. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/param (2).

But it's not clear to me how to construct this `param_type` object that it takes in. Could someone provide an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change a distribution parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372520/can-i-change-a-distribution-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear from the documentation, but here it is:

```
auto d = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{1, 10};

d.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type{11, 24});
```

---

Here's how you can find this information in the docs:

[`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

> ### Member types
>
> `param_type`: the type of the parameter set, see
> [RandomNumberDistribution](http://RandomNumberDistribution.).

[RandomNumberDistribution](http://RandomNumberDistribution.)

> `P`, the type named by `D::param_type`, which
>
> - [...]
> - has a constructor taking identical arguments as each of the constructors of `D` that take arguments corresponding to the
>   distribution parameters.

So basically `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type` has a constructor taking identical arguments as `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>`.